# In the metadata for GIS shapefile, what is the syncdate?

Tags: qgis, metadata

I'm trying to discern when the files were last updated, but the sync date appears to be more recent than the date created, so I just wanted to check if sync date was the date the file was updated?

Comment: If you mean by "updated" "the last time features were added, removed or their attributes changed" just orient yourself by the `.dbf` file.

Comment: Probably indeed the last updated metadata in the .dbf part. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388282/way-i-can-find-out-when-a-shapefile-was-created-or-last-updated/388290#388290.